# isomorphism of normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism

I am reading group theory (particularly isomorphism) in the algebra, and stuck on a problem. Hope you guys will help me out:
Let $G$ be finite group, and $A$,$B$ be  normal subgroups of $G$ such that $G=AB$. Prove that $G/(A \cap B)\cong G/A \times G/B$

Answer (score 2):

**HINT:** Use the first isomorphism theorem on the map
$$G\ \longrightarrow\ G/A\times G/B.$$
Why is this map surjective?